# Woocommerce PHP - Add product image to the page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I hope this isn't to vague. Please ask if you need more info.

I am creating a custom WooCommerce product page from scratch using WooCommerce's hooks.
I am trying to include the product images using this

`<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails' );?>`

I've found online that it has been discontinued, does anyone know how to include product images now? Note, I am looking for the main image, not the gallery.

Thanks in advance, again, let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the main product thumbnail by getting the `image_id` from the product object and use it in the `wp_get_attachment_image()` function:

`wp_get_attachment_image( $product->get_image_id() )`

More information on the arguments you can pass to this function here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/